# Rotate view like animation given in gif

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I need to make view animation like given in below gif. I successfully make view but stuck at the animation because view rotated at 45 degree angle.
[image]

> Here is the constraint of the view

[image]

> Here is the actual animation gif

[image]

Comment: you should use collection view and have to provide custome attributes for that it will be easy to achieve this kind of animation with collection view

Comment: @DevilDecoder thanks for replay is there any tutorial for this kind of animation?

Comment: you should checkout tutoials for carousal effect  but you have to modify the attributes

Comment: @DevilDecoder but i have doubt that it is not possible with collection view and carousal because view rotate at 45 degree

Comment: it not rotating may be it seems translating the view

Comment: @DevilDecoder but how my view display like diamond shape like in initially

Comment: you can do it by modifying the attributes in collectionviewLayout class you have to override the class and have to modify its attribute

Comment: I don't see any rotation; that is just an illusion.  I would just create three views, then you just animate them as required.  At the end of the animation you move them back to their starting position and switch the contents so that it looks like they have remained in place.  In the first instance your left hand view is hidden until the end of the first animation

Comment: @Paulw11 it is not just easy as you know there are moving in at specific direction

Comment: There are five views.  One off-screen left, one left (which is hidden in your starting position), one top/centre, one right and one off-screen right.  When you start a counter-clockwise "rotation" the left ones move down/left.  The top moves down/left and the right ones move up/right.  At the end of the animation you move them back to their starting position (no animation) and update the images, so that the left has the image that was at the centre and so on.  A clockwise rotation is the opposite animations

Comment: @Paulw11 i already think about that solution but when i rotate the view it will not work as aspected

Comment: @chiragshah take reference from this tutorial link:-https://www.raywenderlich.com/1702-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-a-spinning-wheel

Comment: @VDPurohit sure but it is very old and no more working in swift 3

Comment: @chiragshah hey man use his logic just search which method used in swift 3 instead of that old method.

Comment: @VDPurohit ya sure

Comment: Here is my version - https://github.com/paulw11/Rotor

Comment: @Paulw11 you saved by day pls post this as answer. I will accept